# How do I group by the count value in sql

Tags: sql

Say I have

```
SELECT *, count(userid) 
FROM stars 
GROUP by userid
```

How do I change the `GROUP by userid` to group by the `count(userid)`

I searched google but couldn't find anything.

For those stuck: I want to count how many users have X amount of stars.

Comment: Please add example data and expected output

Comment: what are you trying to do?

Comment: I want to group by `count(userid)` http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/007c1/1 to count how many users have X stars.

Comment: you can not do * if you want to do group by count

Comment: I believe he wants to group users by the number of stars they have and count how many of them have x stars.
So you first group the table with stars awarded and you have the ammount of stars each user has. Ex.: A has 1 star, B has 2 stars and C has 1 star.
Then you group again to know how many users have each number of stars. Ex.: 2 users have 1 star, 1 user has 2 stars.

Comment: @Edu You're correct.

Comment: @desbest If I am correct, then you should put it on the question, because it helps describe your objective.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use two levels of `group by`:

```
select cnt, count(*), min(userid), max(userid)
from (select userid, count(*) as cnt
      from stars
      group by userid
     ) u
group by cnt
order by cnt;
```

I call this type of query a "histogram of histograms" query.  I include the `min()` and `max()` values because I often find those useful for further investigation.